# Android Maps API v2 draw circle

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Having the following code to draw circle (taken from Google Play Services "maps" sample):

```
    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
    int radius = 5; //What is that?
    int numPoints = 100;
    double phase = 2 * Math.PI / numPoints;
    for (int i = 0; i <= numPoints; i++) {
        options.add(new LatLng(SYDNEY.latitude + radius * Math.sin(i * phase),
                SYDNEY.longitude + radius * Math.cos(i * phase)));
    }
    int color = Color.RED;
    mMap.addPolyline(options
            .color(color)
            .width(2));
```

This is what gets drawn on different part of the world:

[image: Sydney]
[image: Scandic]

As you see circles are not really circles and even second one is ellipse basically.

I guess that "anti-aliasing" of circle depending on number of points in `int numPoints` variable.

1. What is `int radius = 5` variable in example code? I mean what measure it is?
2. And main question what would be correct way of drawing nice circle with given radius in **meters**? Something smiliar to what we had in api v1 with `canvas.drawCircle()`

UPDATE --------------------

OK after improving math I was able to draw "right" circle:

```
private void addCircle(LatLng latLng, double radius)
    {
        double R = 6371d; // earth's mean radius in km
        double d = radius/R; //radius given in km
        double lat1 = Math.toRadians(latLng.latitude);
        double lon1 = Math.toRadians(latLng.longitude);         
        PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();
        for (int x = 0; x <= 360; x++)
        {                      
            double brng = Math.toRadians(x);
            double latitudeRad = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(d) + Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(d)*Math.cos(brng));
            double longitudeRad = (lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d)*Math.cos(lat1), Math.cos(d)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(latitudeRad)));             
            options.add(new LatLng(Math.toDegrees(latitudeRad), Math.toDegrees(longitudeRad)));
        }           
        mMap.addPolyline(options.color(Color.BLACK).width(2));          
    }
```

However anti-aliasing of circle I guess is somewhat beyond control, and on *some* zoom levels circle might get ugly:

[image]

Comment: the reason you're getting ellipse it's because the math on the `options.add(` is very basic and pretends the earth is a flat surface, just like before Copernicus. If you draw it on smaller areas you'll get a rounder circle. If you want a precise circle you'll have extend that math to proper take into account the shape of Earth.

Comment: @lija, Any specific reason of using a `Polyline` instead of `Polygon` to draw the circle? I tried using Polygon and i got the same output. So, you have any idea which one of them is best to use? Thank You.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc not really, you could use polygons if you need to have a fill option for instance. Otherwise in this case not a big difference.

Comment: Checkout this library: https://github.com/i-schuetz/map_areas

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How to draw circle in Google Maps v2 (bitmap)

```
// 1. some variables:

    private static final double EARTH_RADIUS = 6378100.0;
    private int offset;

// 2. convert meters to pixels between 2 points in current zoom:

    private int convertMetersToPixels(double lat, double lng, double radiusInMeters) {

         double lat1 = radiusInMeters / EARTH_RADIUS;
         double lng1 = radiusInMeters / (EARTH_RADIUS * Math.cos((Math.PI * lat / 180)));

         double lat2 = lat + lat1 * 180 / Math.PI;
         double lng2 = lng + lng1 * 180 / Math.PI; 

         Point p1 = YourActivity.getMap().getProjection().toScreenLocation(new LatLng(lat, lng));
         Point p2 = YourActivity.getMap().getProjection().toScreenLocation(new LatLng(lat2, lng2));

         return Math.abs(p1.x - p2.x);
    }

// 3. bitmap creation:

    private Bitmap getBitmap() {

        // fill color
        Paint paint1 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint1.setColor(0x110000FF);
        paint1.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        // stroke color
        Paint paint2 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint2.setColor(0xFF0000FF);
        paint2.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

        // icon
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(YourActivity.getResources(), R.drawable.blue);

        // circle radius - 200 meters
        int radius = offset = convertMetersToPixels(lat, lng, 200);

        // if zoom too small
        if (radius < icon.getWidth() / 2) {

            radius = icon.getWidth() / 2;
        }

        // create empty bitmap 
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius * 2, radius * 2, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);

        // draw blue area if area > icon size
        if (radius != icon.getWidth() / 2) {

            c.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius, paint1);
            c.drawCircle(radius, radius, radius, paint2);
        }

        // draw icon
        c.drawBitmap(icon, radius - icon.getWidth() / 2, radius - icon.getHeight() / 2, new Paint());

        return b;
    }

// 4. calculate image offset:

    private LatLng getCoords(double lat, double lng) {

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        Projection proj = YourActivity.getMap().getProjection();
        Point p = proj.toScreenLocation(latLng);
        p.set(p.x, p.y + offset);

        return proj.fromScreenLocation(p);
    }

// 5. draw:

        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
            options.position(getCoords(lat, lng));
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getBitmap()));

            marker = YourActivity.getMap().addMarker(options);
```

and result:

[image: google maps v2 draw circle]

Comment: Despite your solution got minor bugs, I got an idea. Anyways with v2 API it seems like trivial tasks much harder to implement than before. For instance if I would need to resize this circle when user drags progress bar, I would have to remove marker and create new one which is slow, also I would need to manage lifecycle of bitmap. All this was very simple with Overlay in V1.

Comment: just to add Marker marker = map.addMarker(options.position(latLng)); it working fine

Comment: With circle, I want dim background on the map. Is this possible?

Answer (score 23):

Google made is simple in maps v2. The snippet below demonstrates both drawing markers and circles along with updating their positions together.

```
private Circle mCircle;
private Marker mMarker;
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment)).getMap();
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mGoogleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            if(mCircle == null || mMarker == null){
                drawMarkerWithCircle(latLng);
            }else{
                updateMarkerWithCircle(latLng);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void updateMarkerWithCircle(LatLng position) {
    mCircle.setCenter(position);
    mMarker.setPosition(position);
}

private void drawMarkerWithCircle(LatLng position){
    double radiusInMeters = 100.0;
    int strokeColor = 0xffff0000; //red outline
    int shadeColor = 0x44ff0000; //opaque red fill

    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions().center(position).radius(radiusInMeters).fillColor(shadeColor).strokeColor(strokeColor).strokeWidth(8);
    mCircle = mGoogleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(position);
    mMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Android 2.0 API you can use CircleOption to draw a circle, works really well, no messy conversions of pixels to meters.

```
public CircleOptions getCircleOptions() {
    CircleOptions co = new CircleOptions();
    co.center(latlng);
    co.radius(getCircleSize());
    co.fillColor(getCircleColor());
    co.strokeColor(getStrokeColor());
    co.strokeWidth(2.0f);
    return co;
}

    Circle circle = mapView.getMap().addCircle(munzeeMarker.getCircleOptions());
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's my code, just for added variation. I haven't found a way to solve the problems with antialiasing or shape simplification:

```
// Make a circle of latitude and longitude points.
// Radius is in metres.
// Probably won't work if the circle is large or near the poles.
private ArrayList<LatLng> makeCircle(LatLng centre, double radius)
{
    ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    double EARTH_RADIUS = 6378100.0;
    // Convert to radians.
    double lat = centre.latitude * Math.PI / 180.0;
    double lon = centre.longitude * Math.PI / 180.0;

    for (double t = 0; t <= Math.PI * 2; t += 0.1)
    {
        // y
        double latPoint = lat + (radius / EARTH_RADIUS) * Math.sin(t);
        // x
        double lonPoint = lon + (radius / EARTH_RADIUS) * Math.cos(t) / Math.cos(lat);
        points.add(new LatLng(latPoint * 180.0 / Math.PI, lonPoint * 180.0 / Math.PI));
    }

    return points;
}
```

## Explanation of maths

Google Earth uses the [Mercator projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection) which means that physical circles do not appear as circles on the map - instead they are distorted as shown in the question. The closer to the poles you go the more distorted they are. To draw a circle on the map but with coordinates given in latitude/longitude we need to invert the distortion.

First we find the centre of the circle in radians - that is pretty simple and is stored in `lat` and `lon`.

Then we go around the circle finding points on its edge. If we were making a physical circle, the latitude and longitude of each point is just:

```
        double latPoint = lat + (radius / EARTH_RADIUS) * Math.sin(t);
        double lonPoint = lon + (radius / EARTH_RADIUS) * Math.cos(t);
```

That's pretty simple trigonometry. The (radius / EARTH_RADIUS) is the *angular* radius of the circle in radians (e.g. a circle with a radius of 100 m would have an angular radius of 0.000015 rad).

If we used that simple code we would find that the circle shown on the map was squished by `cos(lat)` horizontally, so we simply divide by `cos(lat)` to unsquish it.

We could equally have done this:

```
        double latPoint = lat + (radius / EARTH_RADIUS) * Math.sin(t) * Math.cos(lat);
        double lonPoint = lon + (radius / EARTH_RADIUS) * Math.cos(t);
```

Resulting in a large circle - it depends whether the `radius` function parameter refers to latitude or longitude.

This explanation could use some diagrams but I can't be bothered, sorry.

Comment: Can you explain the math here?

Comment: I have added a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Google today, Feb 26, just released Circle as an overlay type.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle

Answer (score 1):

Yesterday Android Developer team intoduced Google Play service v3. Abuse it! ;)
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#circles