# Drawing multiple circle on Google Map V2 API

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw the circle in Google map V2. I have tried using Ground overlay but its not showing as i want.

Comment: please show some code. or use https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lines#polygons

Comment: When i was using V1 map then i used projection.toPixels(mGeoPoint, mScreenCoords); , i want to know the replacement of this projection in V2 map.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13991301/android-maps-api-v2-draw-circle

Comment: please add your code example to fix the problem

Answer (score -1):

You can add a circle to google map ad follows:

```
    GoogleMap gMap = ...; //get ref to gMap
    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();
    circleOptions.center(latLang point);
    circleOptions.fillColor(/* add fill color here */);
    circleOptions.strokeColor(/* add stoke color here*/);
    circleOptions.strokeWidth(/* stroke width here*/);

   Circle circle = this.getMap().addCircle(circleOptions);
```

You can use this circle object later to remove it from map if you want.