# Android - Animate Rotation of Map Marker Around X- and Y-axis

Tags: android, animation, canvas, rotation, marker

I wonder if it is be possible to animate Google Maps markers rotations along x- and y-axis like how we'd rotate an ImageView using ObjectAnimator around x-axis and/or y-axis. Apparently, one can rotate (change) the orientation of a marker clockwise, which is along z-axis (in X-Y plane), but I seem to be unable to find something similar for even rotating a marker (bitmap) around x- or y-axis. I have found few discussions like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79484/android-how-to-create-fluent-animations-by-using-bitmaps-and-objectanimator) which might be somehow related to what I'm looking for but I am rather confused on how to go about this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE I**
I did further research and came up with a proposal on how to tackle this problem:

1. Google Map `Marker` has a setter method for setting its icon, referred to as `setIcon`. Not only through the `MarkerOption` but also as an standalone method to reset the `Marker` icon. This method expects a `BitmapDescriptor` to be passed in in order to update the icon. Using `BitmapDescriptorFactory` one can easily get a `BitmapDescriptor` from a given `Bitmap` object.
2. Since Google Maps `Marker` doesn't support 3D rotations, we need to somehow rotate the `Bitmap` which goes in place of the `Marker` icon outside of the `Marker` itself. One way to do this, as far as my findings go, to create a `Canvas` and a `Camera` objects, while former is linked to the `Drawable` to be 3D rotated, the latter is used to actually perform the 3D rotations.
3. Using `Camera` helper methods like `rotateX`, `rotateY`, and `rotateZ`, in addition to any necessary translations, one can obtain a customized `Matrix` instance. By applying this `Matrix` to `Canvas` using, for example, `concat` or `setMatrix` method, we enforce the the rotations.
4. The drawable can be linked to `Canvas`, that is, we may use `Drawable.draw(Canvas canvas)` method to actually draw into the `Bitmap` while 3D transformations are applied. Assuming that the `Canvas` object is linked to the `Bitmap`. This way the transformed version of the drawable should now be held by the `Bitmap` instance.
5. Using `Marker` setter method `setIcon`, we first recycle the older `BitmapDescriptor` and then create a new one, and pass that object to `setIcon`.

**Questions:** I wonder if this is the best way to accomplish what I'm looking for. Moreover, how to actually accomplish an animation. I am certain an approach like the one using `Animation` and overriding it `applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)` won't work as it is only applicable to `View` objects. I further believe I'm better off using `ValueAnimator` which provides the necessary timing engine for running animations, that is calculating the animated values and set them on target object, in this case the rotation value.

**UPDATE II**
I have come up with the following snippet which is pretty much self-explanatory. Unfortunately, once the animation starts, the icon is removed and nothing else. I captured the logs to make sure the `ValueAnimator` actually works and it turns out that it does indeed. I also removed all transformations and made sure the `Matrix` is identity but that didn't help. Getting the `Drawable` and attempting to draw that into `Bitmap` instance via `Canvas` still doesn't work. In fact, when the animation begins, the icon is simply removed. To verify if bitmap file is really created to be replaced, I tried to sample and save the bitmap into SDCARD as PNG format. It's confirmed that the saved PNGs are all blank and that's why the icon is seen to be removed. Any thought?

```
    private void animateMarker() {
    if (mCamera == null) {
        mCamera = new Camera();
    }

    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
    animator.setDuration(300);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
//              float interpolatedTime = ((Float) (animation.getAnimatedValue())).floatValue();
//              final double radians = Math.PI * interpolatedTime;
//              float degrees = (float) (180.0 * radians / Math.PI);
                final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

//              mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, (float) (150.0 * Math.sin(radians)));
//              mCamera.rotateX(degrees);
//              mCamera.rotateY(degrees);
//              mCamera.rotateZ(degrees);
//              mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);

                Resources resources = mContext.getResources();
                Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_pin);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(),
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
//              mCamera.applyToCanvas(canvas);
//              canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
//              drawable.draw(canvas);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
                mMarkerSetLocation.setIcon(mBitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
        }
    });
    animator.start();
}
```