# Fixed (zoom independent) Rectangle Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, shapes, offline

How to add on map an rectangle representing 80% width and 80% height of the screen like Maps offline area selection screen. I need to get the LatLngBound of this rectangle, a LinearLayout may not be the solution here.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `LatLon` coordinates of pixel by [`getProjection()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getProjection()) method, and draw everything you want in [`onDraw()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)) method of [custom view](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html).

So, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36763696/6950238) answer of [NSimon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4232337/nsimon) just add custom view (e.g. `FrameView`) with needed transparency over `MapFragment` in your map activity layout xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<[your_package].FrameView
    android:id="@+id/frame_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

where `[your_package].FrameView` is

```
public class FrameView extends View {

    private Paint mTransparentPaint;
    private Paint mBorderPaint;
    private Paint mSemiBlackPaint;
    private Path mPath = new Path();
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap = null;
    private float x1, y1, x2, y2;

    public FrameView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public FrameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public FrameView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mTransparentPaint = new Paint();
        mTransparentPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mTransparentPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mBorderPaint = new Paint();
        mBorderPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mBorderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mBorderPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        mSemiBlackPaint = new Paint();
        mSemiBlackPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mSemiBlackPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        x1 = 0.1f * canvas.getWidth();
        y1 = 0.1f * canvas.getHeight();
        x2 = 0.9f * canvas.getWidth();
        y2 = 0.8f * canvas.getHeight();

        mPath.reset();

        mPath.addRect(x1, y1, x2, y2, Path.Direction.CW);
        mPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_EVEN_ODD);

        canvas.drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2, mTransparentPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(x1, y1, x2, y2, mBorderPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mSemiBlackPaint);

        canvas.clipPath(mPath);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#83000000"));
    }

    public void setMap(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    }

    public LatLng getTopLeft() {
        return point2LatLng(new Point((int)x1, (int)y1));
    }

    public LatLng getTopRight() {
        return point2LatLng(new Point((int)x2, (int)y1));
    }

    public LatLng getBottomLeft() {
        return point2LatLng(new Point((int)x1, (int)y2));
    }

    public LatLng getBottomRight() {
        return point2LatLng(new Point((int)x2, (int)y2));
    }

    public LatLng point2LatLng(Point point) {
        if (mGoogleMap != null) {
            Projection projection = mGoogleMap.getProjection();
            return projection.fromScreenLocation(point);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

where x1, x2, y1, y2 - coordinates of "frame" rectangle in pixels.

Than you need get `FrameView` object in `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFrameView = (FrameView) findViewById(R.id.frame_view);
    mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    ...
}
```

and set `GoogleMap` object for `mFrameView` in `onMapReady()`:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mFrameView.setMap(mGoogleMap);
    ...
}
```

and now you can get `LatLon` coords by `mFrameView.getTopLeft()`, `mFrameView.getTopRight()` etc. calls when you need it:

[image]

NB! This is just quick and dirty example of custom component.

Comment: The getProjection() was the part I missed...Sounds perfect !! Why do you say "quick and dirty" ?

Comment: @Daminox Because in right way `FrameView` and `GoogleMap` should be one composite custom view: `setMap()` is working, but not very nice method. And there is no need to create new `Point` object on every `point2LatLng()` call and `"#83000000"` - bad constant, and dark frame around blue rectangle and so on  :)

Comment: Ok, so in this case I should not use MapFragment but a custom fragment. Is it right ?

Comment: @Daminox Yes, custom map fragment.