# How Can I Invert a Border In XML Shape?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, shapes

I am trying to get a rectangle shape in Android XML (Kotlin) to have an inverted top right border. By this, I mean rather than a curved, rounded top right border going to the left, i'd like it to round off to the right, like a sharp point before going back across the top to top left.

To explain what I mean, please find some screenshots below.

**What i've got so far**
[image]

**What i'm aiming for**

[image]

In terms of code so far, using some examples elsewhere on Stack Overflow, I have produced the below. This is quite simply a white shape with a border top left radius, placed over the top of a green-background shape, to the right of a green shape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/rsMoving"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="200dp" android:right="30dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/rsMoving" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:left="200dp" android:right="0dp" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="50dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

In terms of research, i've had a look at some examples, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53646942/how-to-make-a-rectangle-with-inverted-rounded-corners), but having tried to add other shapes

However I'm looking for some suggestions on how to better produce this, because I don't think fixed dimensions and sizes are going to work. On my screenshots above, the green background text is variable width so ideally I need a shape that will maintain its top right inverted border, but have a dynamically resizing width.

If anyone can point me in the right direction of a top right inverted border i'd be grateful. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55377936/7924565

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good application of a [9-patch drawable](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch). There is a little bit of a learning curve, but 9-patch drawables can be useful.

I took you image a sliced out the part that has the text and loaded it into Android Studio applying the patches.

[image]

The black bars on the left and top identify the regions that can expand to grow the drawable. The right and bottom bars identify where text can be placed. Using this XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/sample"
        android:text="This is some wider text!"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/sample"
        android:text="This is some text!"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

we see the following

[image]

Android Studio (Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2) does not display this 9-patch correctly, but it does appear as shown here on an emulator.

Comment: Thankyou very much , so just to clarify, I should set one textview left (with the green background and text), and then a second textview with a drawable with the green inverted corner constrained beside it?

Comment: @trainmania100 I don't understand your comment. The layout is two independent _TextViews_ with the same 9-patch drawable as a background. The 9-patch file name is _sample.9.png_.

Comment: Thanks I'll mark as answer as your post looks good, I am unfamiliar with 9 patch so will do some research. Thankyou