# How to place a circle over google maps?

Tags: android, maps

I'm trying to implement a Map in Android, the pointer has to be fixed in the center of the map(Surrounded by the circle of dynamic radius) and the map moves in the background.

I was able to establish this by placing an ImageView(as a pointer) on the top of the map Fragment and Catching the Longitude and Latitude of the center of the map.

However, when trying to add a circle (of dynamic radius) around the pointer, it is failing to appear. I am Using the following code

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions.center(latlng)
    .radius(radius)
    .strokeWidth(2)
    .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
    .fillColor(Color.parseColor("#500084d3"));
mMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

The circle is not appearing and no error is being shown.

Do I have to add a MarkerOptions for the circle to appear? Or is there any workaround for this?

Help is appreciated

Comment: Just use a simple `ImageView` on your XML layout.

Comment: To draw circle in Google Maps v2 (bitmap)
[Try this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428226/9404855) it help you